# Django loop through a form multiple choice field

Tags: django

I am very new to django and I'm making a project that tracks medications in our drug safe. Part of our daily activities is to check the amount of each drug in the safe and document each amount. In my model for the safe, I have a field "drug_name" that is a foreign key to a list of medications. I want to make a model form that auto populates each choice in the field and asks for the amount of the drug in the safe. Something like:

Drug Name 1

Amount:_________

Drug Name 2

Amount:_________

and so on. 
Here is my model

```
class Safe(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    drug_name = models.ForeignKey('components.Drug', related_name='drug_remove', on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=0, limit_choices_to={'is_active': True})
    amount_removed = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    amount_added = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    amount_in_safe = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    incident_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=0, blank=True)
    patient_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=0, blank=True)
    medic_unit = models.ForeignKey('components.MedicUnit', related_name='medic_unit', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    free_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=0, blank =True)
```

I'm not sure if I could submit all at once or if I would have to submit one drug at a time. Either way would work well as long as the user didn't have to manually select each medication. Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Comment: check this tutorial maybe help you https://dev.to/zxenia/django-inline-formsets-with-class-based-views-and-crispy-forms-14o6

Comment: Thank you so much for the tutorial. I just skimmed it, but I think it will help.